Setting up of IPFS node to remix settings
I am not able to publish on IPFS. Getting this error -
Failed to publish metadata file and sources to ipfs, please check the ipfs gateways is available. Error: HTTPError: project id required

Also, it seems like IPFS is currently disabled by https://app.infura.io/dashboard. How should I connect to IPFS?
